# How do you get buttons inside a div only? no JQuery

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="keys">
    <button id="a"></button>
    <button id="b"></button>
</div>
```

I have a lot of buttons and I only want to `get` the ones inside the `<div>` with `class="keys"`, but I can't get it to work,
so far I tried:

```
content = document.getElementsByClassName("keys");
kbButtons = content.getElementsByTagName("button");
```

and I just get undefined

Comment: Can there be more than one DIV with `class="keys"`?

Comment: @Barmar nope, just checked again to make sure, only 1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Notice how the method is named "getElements...", plural.

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an HTMLCollection, an array-like object.

```
content = document.getElementsByClassName("keys")[0];
kbButtons = content.getElementsByTagName("button");
```

You can access the first element of the HTMLCollection with the `[0]` bracket syntax.

Answer (score 8):

I like the querySelector, if you know css selectors this is really powerfull.

`kbButtons = document.querySelectorAll('div.keys button');`

Comment: Or, if you just want one result, use simply `document.querySelector`.

Comment: You can get the css selector for any element using developer tools. On Firefox: right click the element in the developer tools window->copy->CSS Selector. Paste what you get into your query selector like so: `const centerButton = document.querySelector('.array1 > button:nth-child(2)');`

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements, but `getElementsByTagName` can only be applied to a single element, not a list. You need to select one element out of the list:

```
kbButtons = content[0].getElementsByTagName("button");
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript returns an array of dom elements with the function 'getElementsByClassName'.

Thus, if you have one element that you are targeting with your code, then you need to specify the array element you want.  Otherwise you're saying, "In this array, give me the button elements," when you should actually be asking, "In this array, give me the button elements in the first element of the array."

Here's what your javascript code above should look like...

```
content = document.getElementsByClassName("keys");
kbButtons = content[0].getElementsByTagName("button");

for (var iIndex = 0; iIndex < kbButtons.length; iIndex++){
    alert(kbButtons[iIndex].id);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
kbButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('keys')[0].getElementsByTagName('button')
```